# A contract function can be called after a certain time?

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, contract-invocation

Let's say for bidding implementation of blockchain for a time bound process how it will be executed

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the contract to be active for transactions received only after a certain block as you can get the block number inside the contract using `block.number` and then if a bid is received after a specific block you can ignore it. Reference to a sample can be found [here](https://github.com/dob/auctionhouse/blob/master/contracts/AuctionHouse.sol).